# File creation problem in python, receiving unexpected output

Tags: python, file-io

So at first I searched for filenames in my pwd and then if name match it will print File Exists, but I can't understand why I'm receiving output like this.

```
import os

filenames = os.listdir()

for names in filenames:
    if names == "abc.txt":
        print("FIle Exists, Please Remove Old File And Try Again")
    else:
        with open("abc.txt","w") as file:
            file.write("abcde\n"*10000)
            with open("abc.txt") as file:
                print(file.read(10))
```

Output :

```
abcde
FIle Exists, Please Remove Old File And Try Again
abcde
abcde
abcde
abcde
abcde
abcde
abcde
```

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: When your loop gets to another file that isn't named `abc.txt`, it goes to the `else:` block and overwrites the `abc.txt` file.

Comment: Before you open the file for reading you should either close the writing file or use `file.flush()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I found my solution, thank you all.

```
import os 

filenames = os.listdir()
        for names in filenames:
            if names == "abc.txt":
                print("FIle Exists, Please Remove Old File And Try Again")
                break
        else:
            with open("abc","w") as file:
                file.write("abcde\n"*10000)
            with open("abc.txt") as file:
                print(file.read(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code does exactly what it should do:

```
for all names in your directory:
   if name is 'abc.txt':
       program prints your message
   in other case:
       you opens the file 'abc.txt' and writes 10000 lines
       then you opens it again and reads first 10 lines
```

Python is indent dependent language, make sure that you use them correctly.